# Java web application does not work on I.E after some seconds but works on Firefox

Tags: apache, tomcat7, mod-jk

we just migrated our web applications from tomcat5 to tomcat7. Both tomcats are running behind an apache web server.
After the migration the applications are working without problems on Firefox.
On I.E they are also working but after user inactivity of around 10 seconds we get the 404 error page displayed.

Configuration:

- Apache version:1.3.29 (we will also migrate this to apache 2 in few weeks)
- mod_jk version: 1.2.6
- Tomcat version: 7.0.59 (running on two different servers)
- Internet explorer version : 10
- Firefox version: 36.0
- I.E & Firefox versions are the same on every computer in our Network.

What could be the reason behind this? any advices are welcome.

Best Regards
Arthur

Edit:
Yes, sorry for that: the following logs are available

### error_log

```
[error] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] File does not exist: /usr/local/apache/htdocs/App3
[error] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] File does not exist: /usr/local/apache/htdocs/App1
[error] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] File does not exist: /usr/local/apache/htdocs/App2
```

### mod_jk.log

```
[jk_ajp_common.c (783)]: ERROR: can't receive the response message from tomcat, network problems or tomcat is down (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8009), err=-1
[jk_ajp_common.c (1250)]: Tomcat is down or network problems. No response has been sent to the client (yet)
[jk_ajp_common.c (1449)]: ERROR: Receiving from tomcat failed, recoverable operation. err=0
[jk_ajp_common.c (1468)]: sending request to tomcat failed in send loop. err=0
[jk_connect.c (188)]: jk_open_socket, connect() failed errno = 111
[jk_ajp_common.c (720)]: Error connecting to tomcat. Tomcat is probably not started or is listening on the wrong host/port (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8009). Failed errno = 111
[jk_ajp_common.c (1024)]: Error connecting to the Tomcat process.
[jk_ajp_common.c (1468)]: sending request to tomcat failed in send loop. err=1
[jk_connect.c (188)]: jk_open_socket, connect() failed errno = 111
[jk_ajp_common.c (720)]: Error connecting to tomcat. Tomcat is probably not started or is listening on the wrong host/port (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8009). Failed errno = 111
[jk_ajp_common.c (1024)]: Error connecting to the Tomcat process.
[jk_ajp_common.c (1468)]: sending request to tomcat failed in send loop. err=2
[jk_ajp_common.c (1477)]: Error connecting to tomcat. Tomcat is probably not started or is listening on the wrong port. worker=worker1 failed errno = 111
[jk_ajp_common.c (783)]: ERROR: can't receive the response message from tomcat, network problems or tomcat is down (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8009), err=-1
[jk_ajp_common.c (1250)]: Tomcat is down or network problems. No response has been sent to the client (yet)
[jk_ajp_common.c (1449)]: ERROR: Receiving from tomcat failed, recoverable operation. err=0
[jk_ajp_common.c (1468)]: sending request to tomcat failed in send loop. err=0
[jk_ajp_common.c (783)]: ERROR: can't receive the response message from tomcat, network problems or tomcat is down (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8009), err=-1
[jk_ajp_common.c (1250)]: Tomcat is down or network problems. No response has been sent to the client (yet)
[jk_ajp_common.c (1449)]: ERROR: Receiving from tomcat failed, recoverable operation. err=0
[jk_ajp_common.c (1468)]: sending request to tomcat failed in send loop. err=0
[jk_ajp_common.c (783)]: ERROR: can't receive the response message from tomcat, network problems or tomcat is down (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8009), err=-1
[jk_ajp_common.c (1250)]: Tomcat is down or network problems. No response has been sent to the client (yet)
[jk_ajp_common.c (1449)]: ERROR: Receiving from tomcat failed, recoverable operation. err=0
[jk_ajp_common.c (1468)]: sending request to tomcat failed in send loop. err=0
[jk_ajp_common.c (783)]: ERROR: can't receive the response message from tomcat, network problems or tomcat is down (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8009), err=-1
[jk_ajp_common.c (1250)]: Tomcat is down or network problems. No response has been sent to the client (yet)
[jk_ajp_common.c (1449)]: ERROR: Receiving from tomcat failed, recoverable operation. err=0
[jk_ajp_common.c (1468)]: sending request to tomcat failed in send loop. err=0
[jk_ajp_common.c (783)]: ERROR: can't receive the response message from tomcat, network problems or tomcat is down (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8009), err=-1
[jk_ajp_common.c (1250)]: Tomcat is down or network problems. No response has been sent to the client (yet)
[jk_ajp_common.c (1449)]: ERROR: Receiving from tomcat failed, recoverable operation. err=0
```

Comment: Any exceptions or errors logged in Apache server?

Comment: Yes, sorry for that: